# PowerShell for loop from file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS script to loop from a file(names of the folders).  I'm trying to get the NTFS permissions from a file with 400 folder names. I know the command how do I write a scrip to loop at a variable that points to a file of all the folder names.  Thanks in advance.

(Get-Acl -Path .$foldername).Access |ft

Comment: Is it a text file? A CSV file? What ya working with? Loops can be intimidating but, are quite user friendly. Say you have a text file with all the names: `MyTextFile.TXT`. We can get the content of the file using `Get-Content` and assign it to a variable: `$MyPaths`. Then, using a `foreach` loop, we can iterate through each path, one at a time getting the desire result. `$MyPaths = Get-Content .\MyTextFile.txt; foreach ($path in $MyPaths) { (Get-Acl -Path .$Path).Access |ft }` where `$Path` stands for the current line/path in the file.

Comment: It's a text file.  I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: Does the file contain the fullpath of each folder?  Do all folders exists? If not you will get some errors which need to be handled.